# What weapons would nanomachines use?

Tags: science-based, creature-design, weapons, nanotechnology

So, the strongest of my current characters is a happy little cloud, that's composed of nanomachines (well, not exactly nano, it's well in the micro prefix, but individual parts obviously require nanotechnology) and I struggle to pin down its fighting style and "strength"

The properties of a nanite:

- Basically the robotic version of a [fairyfly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kikiki).
- Its outer shell is made out of [high-entropy alloys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_entropy_alloys#Mechanical)
- It possesses some computing power.
- Its antennas are elongated.
- A unit can connect to others by linking either the legs or the antenna together with another unit's legs or antennae.
- They have Lithium batteries, with a [little help](https://www.todaysmotorvehicles.com/article/asphalt-helps-lithium--batteries-charge-faster/), to charge faster

The swarms:

- Usually, share data and energy through [induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_power_transfer#Inductive_coupling)
- Alternatively, Tamás Tihanyi can [send them energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_power_transfer#Far-field_(radiative)_techniques), and only energy from afar.
- Can vary in size, from  1 cm^3 to 1000 m^3, there are even larger swarms, but we're currently ignoring them
- Density is also variable, usually 0,1 g/cm^3

**My question is, what kind of armament could they use against bulk *(you, and your inanimate belongings)* and similarly sized *(fellow nanite)* enemies?**

Priorities (from high to low):

- Efficiency
- Damage
- Costs

---

I know these are two separate questions, but as one's influence on the other is likely great, they should be addressed **together**.

Comment: How does fighting against Humans and other mammals influence how to fight other small/tiny machines?

Comment: @Soan Well, nanites need to be economic with their power, and carrying two sets of weapons is sorta detrimental, I think.

Comment: Who the love is Tamás?

Comment: @Renan He's a meme.

Comment: Two questions = two posts.  If one could greatly influence the other, ask that question first.  VTC OT:TB.

Comment: I think you need to do some serious work on this question. It is too broad (two questions = too broad). I'm confused on definitions --- a 0.1mm machine is clearly not a nanomachine. I don't what your micromachines look like or what their capacities are, so really can not even speculate as to what kinds of weapons they'd be able to use. VTC.

Answer (score 3):

### Solution 1:

**Against Humans:**

If the Humans aren't fully armored your machines can simply use a sting to insert nanobots into the human blood system or into the brain where they can destroy vital parts of the body. Either destroy connections between brain parts or clog important blood veins.

**Against fellow machines:**

The nanobots could destroy the connections between the processor and the wings removing the mobility of the machine.

### Solution 2:

**Against Humans:**

Use a toxin that is already lethal in very small amounts.

**Against fellow machines:**

Ideally the toxin used to fight Humans would be corrosive at the same time to also be used against other machines.

Comment: The OP established that their "nanobots" are in the micro range, at ~150 micrometers, rather than cellular scale.  They wouldn't be injecting smaller nanobots.

Comment: @jdunlop Doesn't mean that there are none? There still could be Nanobots the OP only stated that the machines in question are bigger.

Answer (score 2):

Against anything - coat the target in nanites and break the target down into it's component molecules. For complex machinery, start at the joints to immobilize the target.

Comment: How would they break them down?

Comment: Just start breaking off pieces. The fancy word is "mechanical digestion"

Comment: Can I vibrate the mandibles?

Comment: Of course. They're your nanites. That's a common strategy in improving the cutting ability of a tool - think of an electric knife or a jackhammer for examples of the principle

Comment: I had leafcutter ants in mind, but okay.

Answer (score 1):

**Large creatures.**

It is an easy thing for the nanites to take over the body of a large creature.  First they go up the nose or through the ear and incapacitate the higher functions of the brain.  Then they distribute themselves throughout the neurons, and take over the role of the brain in running the creature.  In their favored species, they can replicate any action the creature could do in life and also perform many that such creatures would never have tried.

Large creatures are preferable because they have large neurons and as pointed out, the nanites are small but not microscopic.  Larger neurons are easier.  As neurons get smaller the precision of control decreases and movements of the commandeered creature get rough and jerky.  Humans are on the small end of what they can commandeer.  They have their uses, but a nanite commandeered human would not pass for normal very long.

Large creatures are great for fighting other large creatures, although better is to commandeer other large creatures if there are enough excess nanites available.  Large creatures are also great for fighting other nanites - they can inhale or ingest them.  Should the opposing nanite force gain access thru the eye or ear and try to hijack the commandeered creature it will be hand to hand fighting with the home team.